# do static variables survive instances in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, static

I already understand that `static` in objective-c is different from `static` in say Java. My question is for Objective-c static variables. I have a static variable in Objective-C. If it is set in one instance of a class. Will the value be visible if I were to create a new instance of the class after the variable was previously set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of `static` variables. They are not instance variables. A static variable exists just once in its scope. It is initialized once as well.

This is true for static variables declared outside of any method as well as static variables declared within a method.

Comment: This answer is not correct and should not have been accepted.  The `static` keyword has nothing to do with classes in Objective-C.

Comment: @Droppy It's not incorrect. As stated, the static variable is independent of any class instance (or any classes). The OP asked about static variables within the scope of a class. That is how it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword is merely used to limit the scope of a variable so that it can only be referenced directly within its implementation file.

The `static` keyword is commonly used with global variables to implement Objective-C's half-baked class variables, so yes, you are correct, that a single instance of the variable will exist regardless of the number of instances of the class (including zero), and that's basically because it's completely unrelated to the class.

Comment: It's not just the implementation file. A static variable in a method of a class is only accessible within that method. File-level statics are declared outside of any class code.

Comment: @rmaddy The OP was asking about class variables (in a round-about manner).  That is how it was answered.